# Как сделать чтобы бот ждал пока пользователь отправит ZIP файл

Tags: python, discord.py, disnake

В интернете искал, не нашел. Там только про картинки, а мне нужно и .ZIP файлы.
Я знаю про `await bot.wait_for()`, но я не знаю как его использовать для ZIP файлов. Он просто не принимает их как сообщение.

Comment: у сообщения есть свойство `discord.Message.attachments`, предоставляющее список всех кложений сообщения. Проверяйте, есть ли у сообщения вложения (`len(message.attachments) > 0`) и если есть, то смотрите на расширение приложенного файла (все свойства есть в [**документациии**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Attachment)) и если это zip-файл, то делайте то, что нужно

Comment: @denisnumb Спасибо, разобрался.